# Consultar nome de usuário com mysql no php

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um website para meu TCC, ainda sou aprendiz em desenvolvimento de sites com php.

Estou tentando fazer com que ao usuário entrar na sua página ele receber boas vindas com seu nome buscado no mysql, segue a foto 1.

[image: Foto 1]

Porém não quero que fique o email, e sim o nome do usuário que entrou na sua conta.
Primeiramente, criei um sessão para verificar se o usuário está logado na sua conta.

```
    <?php 
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha"])) { 
// Usuário não logado! Redireciona para a página de login 
header("Location: index.php"); 
exit; 
}
?>
```

Depois segue abaixo o h2, mostrando as boas-vindas.

```
 <h2>Bem vindo aluno!  <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></h2>
```

Usei uma SESSION para chamar o email apenas para teste, porém quero chamar o nome do usuário sendo o atributo "nome" no mysql. De qual maneira mais fácil eu posso fazer isso?

Levando em consideração que ao colocar o nome ao invés de email, não retorna nada na mensagem de bem vindo.

**OBS: Acrescentando o código PHP, que faz a consulta no banco de dados, e havia esquecidodo de adicionar na pergunta. Segue o código abaixo:**

```
<?php

session_start();
include("conexao.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$sql_logar = "SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";
$exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error());
$num_logar = mysqli_num_rows($exe_logar);

if ($num_logar == 0){

$_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login ou senha incorreto!</div>";
header("Location: index.php?login");
}
else{
//Cria a sessão e verifica tipo de login
while($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_array($exe_logar) ){
$tipo = $percorrer['tipo'];
}

$_SESSION['tipo'] = $tipo;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;

if($tipo != "2"){
header("Location: aluno.php");
}else{
header("Location: administrador.php");
}

}
?>
```

- Estrutura da tabela **aluno**:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://celke.com.br/artigo/sistema-de-login-com-php-e-mysqli

Comment: O sistema de login já fiz amigo, o tópico é outro;

Comment: @HermetoBermudez , você só quer mostrar o Nome ao invés do email, correto ? Ser for isso, é simples. Só você, atribuir a uma $_SESSION['nome'] o nome do usuário (como você faz com o email) e exibir essa $_SESSION['nome'] ou invés de $_SESSION['email']. Tenta editar sua pergunta e adicionar nela a query que você utiliza para preencher as SESSIONS. Para que possamos visualizar e conseguir te ajudar da melhor forma.

Comment: Isso Gambi, pensei assim, tentei mas não deu certo, por que o SESSION que eu atribuo no email é apenas pra verificação, como posso consultar o nome do usuário que entrou?.. por que se colocar só uma $_SESSION['nome'] não da em nada também :/

Comment: Coloca na pergunta o código com a query que você preenche as SESSION, por favor.

Comment: A unica query que uso é a que eu citei acima, depois é apenas body com o site, que consta o h2 do bem vindo,

Comment: Citou onde ? Não conseguir ver, desculpa.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105578/discussion-between-gambi-and-hermeto-bermudez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O usuário não colocou o código PHP que realiza a consulta no banco de dados e retorna os dados que preenche as SESSIONS. Porém, conversando no chat, ele me informou o código (que ele havia feito) e eu adicionei na pergunta.

- Com isso ficou mais fácil identificar o erro.
- O usuário estava adicionando os valores, que vem dos campos do form, diretamente nas SESSIONS, ao invés de adicionar nas SESSIONS os dados resultantes da consulta no banco de dados. (Coisa completamente equivocada, ao meu modo de ver).
- Fiz abaixo um código para ajudá-lo a conseguir seu objetivo. OBS: Fiz com base na sua necessidade atual e vendo uma forma de ajudá-lo a resolver seu problema.

Segue abaixo como ficou o código PHP:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include("conexao.php");

    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    /* Verifica se existe usuario, o segredo ta aqui quando ele procupa uma
    linha q contenha o login e a senha digitada */
    $sql_logar = "SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";
    $exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error());
    $num_logar = mysqli_num_rows($exe_logar);

    //Verifica se n existe uma linha com o login e a senha digitado
    if ($num_logar == 0){

        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login ou senha incorreto!</div>";
        header("Location: index.php?login");
    }
    else{
        //Cria a sessão e verifica tipo de login
        $informacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar);

        $_SESSION['tipo'] = $informacao ['tipo'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $informacao ['email'];
        $_SESSION['senha'] = $informacao ['senha']; //Não tem necessidade disso
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $informacao ['nome'];


        if($_SESSION['tipo'] != "2"){
            header("Location: aluno.php");
        }else{
        header("Location: administrador.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

- O **HTML** ficaria assim:

```html
<h2>Bem vindo aluno!
  <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?>
</h2>
```

- Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @Gambi, obrigado pela ajuda amigo! E boa sorte no seu tcc ;)

Comment: Obrigado, @HermetoBermudez. Boa sorte no seu também. Que a força esteja com você !

Comment: Ah, e segue a dica que o @Eliseu B. te deu no comentário lá de cima e dá uma olhada naquele tutorial do link. É muito bom mesmo.